# Navigation Drawer Background Color

Tags: android, background

I am trying to change the background color of the navigation drawer in android studio.  I didn't write the code myself for the navigation drawer but rather used androids navigation drawer activity when you start a new app so the code was entered automatically.  There code it uses is not the same if you wrote the navigation from scratch.  Therefore, I can't see where in the code I can change background color.  One things I did do though, was to change background color by entering in the activity_main.xml (by adding the last 2 lines to the code of the first line below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    app:itemTextColor="#A9A9A9"     // text color
    android:background="#FF0000" /> // background color
```

which made the navigation drawer look like it was covered with a dark transparent piece of film and you can still see everything underneath including the white background, icons, etc.

Can someone please help or point me in the right direction?
Thanks.
Robert

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Yes.  I agree.  I am new to stackoverlow and I'm not sure how it works.  Now I know.  Thank you.